# scrollview, tablelayout and linearlayout doesnt work together in android

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout, android-tablelayout, android-scrollview

I have a layout xml file which crashes and couldnt understand why. here is my xml, but I am not posting the entire xml.

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

   <TableLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

         <TableRow
        android:background="@drawable/gradient"
        android:gravity="center">

            .......

         </TableRow>

   </TableLayout>

    <ScrollView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/sw_layout"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="#EEEEEE" >

        <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRowDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            ..........

            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_date"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/calendar"
            android:text="Tarih" />

            <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_converter"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/calendar"
            android:text="Hesap" />

        </LinearLayout>
     </ScrollView>  
 </LinearLayout>
```

If I remove the last linearlayout. it works perfectly but I need to add button at the bottom of the screen. How can I add the buttons? I want to add the buttons and center them horizontally

Comment: make sure that scrollview have only one child

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Scrollview` will allow only one child, so you have to kept that `TableLayout` and `LinearLayout` in one more separate layout as child of ScrollView.

Like this

```
<ScrollView

   <LinearLayout

      <TableLayout   />
      <LinearLayout  />

   </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```